# How to get formdata values sent by ajax post method in laravel controller

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, laravel, controller

I am trying to send a set of data including image file through ajax using formdata but when I want to access that data in laravel controller, it shows a blank array.

Here is my ajax code -

```
var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("photo",files[0]);
    fd.append("user_id",localStorage.getItem('userId'));
    fd.append("doctype","dl_image");       
    console.log(fd);



   //ajax code
    $http.post('uploadfile', fd, {    
            withCredentials: true,      
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }       
     }).success(function(data, status) {        

               console.log(data);


     });
```

PHP code -

```
    $data = Request::all();
    $photo = Request::file('photo');
    $userid = Request::get('user_id');
    $doctype = Request::get('doctype');


    $postData = array(
        'photo' => $photo,
        'user_id' => $userid,
        'doctype' => $doctype  
    );
    var_dump($data);
    die();
```

When the data is dumped in browser's console, it shows

```
array(0) {
}
```

Need help.

Comment: Heads up, Angular 5+'s HttpClient sets the content type to FormData automatically if it detects a FormData() object being sent.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS sends POST requests with `application/json` type & `JSON` body by default.
So I think that you need to use:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
data: $.param(data)
```

in `ajax` code.
You might need to use something like `$name = Input::get('name');` instead of `$userid = Request::get('user_id');`

Comment: Accept file? I didn't get you

Answer (score 1):

When using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to POST files and data, it is important to set the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `undefined`.

Try: `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }`

Answer (score 0):

Please try serialize method of jquery.

```
function myForm( form ){
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    att=form.attr("action") ;
    $.post(att, formData).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am using angularJs